# salt-ssh : Disable SSH Host Key Checking with python api

Tags: python, ssh, salt-stack

I'm working with salt-ssh and with the command line I can use option -i to use 'StrictHostKeyChecking'

```
(agent) [root@NODE ~]# salt-ssh  'af0abc4b-6980d-4fdd-ba63-192cb3d116be' test.ping
af0abc4b-6980d-4fdd-ba63-192cb3d116be:
    ----------
    retcode:
        254
    stderr:
    stdout:
        The host key needs to be accepted, to auto accept run salt-ssh with the -i flag:
        The authenticity of host '10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10)' can't be established.
        ECDSA key fingerprint is af:00:b8:ab:7a:3e:cd:06:9a:6c:36:e9:32:f0:a3:a4.
        Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? 

(agent) [root@NODE ~]# salt-ssh -i --no-host-keys 'af0abc4b-6980d-4fdd-ba63-192cb3d116be' test.ping
af0abc4b-6980d-4fdd-ba63-192cb3d116be:
    True
```

but when I want to do the same thing with the python api I didn't find a way to specify the -i option so can it be done.

this is the python code I'm using

```
from salt.client.ssh.client import SSHClient
salt = SSHClient()
salt.cmd('af0abc4b-6980d-4fdd-ba63-192cb3d116be', 'test.ping')
Out: 
{'af0abc4b-6980d-4fdd-ba63-192cb3d116be': {'retcode': 254,
  'stderr': '',
  'stdout': "The host key needs to be accepted, to auto accept run salt-ssh with the -i flag:\nThe authenticity of host '10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10)' can't be established.\nECDSA key fingerprint is af:00:b8:ab:7a:3e:cd:06:9a:6c:36:e9:32:f0:a3:a4.\nAre you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? "}}
```

how can I do the same with the python code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution I found is to configure `StrictHostKeyChecking` in $HOME/.ssh/config`.

example of $HOME/.ssh/config

```
Host *
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

or

```
Host 10.10.10.15
   StrictHostKeyChecking no
```